# JS to apply to each canvas (multiple)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to use [StackBlur.js](http://zurb.com/playground/image-blur-texture) on multiple canvas elements on the same page; however using the example provided by [Zurb](http://zurb.com/playground/image-blur-texture), I can only apply it to the first canvas element; it ignores the others.

Any idea how to make this code more universal to apply to every canvas element, not just to one?

The JS (by Zurb) is this:

```
  $(function() {
  // Change this value to adjust the amount of blur
  var BLUR_RADIUS = 100;

  var canvas = document.querySelector('[data-canvas]');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var image = new Image();
  image.src = document.querySelector('[data-canvas-image]').src;

  var drawBlur = function() {
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
    stackBlurCanvasRGBA('heroCanvas', 0, 0, w, h, BLUR_RADIUS);
  };

  image.onload = function() {
    drawBlur();
  }
});
```

The relevant HTML is this:

```
<canvas class="hero__background" id="heroCanvas" width="200" height="200" data-canvas></canvas>

<!-- Our image to be blurred -->
<img data-canvas-image style="display: none" src="path/to/image.jpg" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap their code in a loop over all elements with that attribute (in this case `data-canvas`) like so

```
$('[data-canvas]').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this);
  // insert their code here and change it to reference the correct image each time
});
```

So in the end you can refer to each of the canvases on the page individually, something like so:

```
$(function(){

  // our iteration
  $('[data-canvas]').each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);

    var BLUR_RADIUS = 100;
    var canvas = this; // canvas is the element we're iterating over
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image();

    // I changed the line below of theirs to refer to the canvases attributes
    // we're iterating over above
    image.src = $el.attr('data-src'); 

    var drawBlur = function() {
      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;
      canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);

      var id = $el.attr('id'); // use the id from the canvas
      stackBlurCanvasRGBA( id, 0, 0, w, h, BLUR_RADIUS); 
    };

    image.onload = function() {
      drawBlur();
    }

  });
});
```

So now we don't need the images only their `src attributes, which now live on the canvases as`data-src`. The the html can be as follows:

```
<canvas class="hero__background" id="heroCanvas1" data-src="/image/location.jpg" width="200" height="200" data-canvas></canvas>
<canvas class="hero__background" id="heroCanvas2" data-src="/image/location2.jpg" width="200" height="200" data-canvas></canvas>
```

**Update**: I realised that you're displaying info in the canvas, and so need more than one. code updated above.

**Update 2**: I realised that stack blur relies on an id for each call so you need to get that from each canvas in turn, updated code above

**Aside**: I would recommend iterating over the canvases by class not attribute, but I used it as that was what was in your html. I'd suggest adding a class to each and changing the iteration to something like so:

```
$('.blurImgCanvas').each(function(){....})
```